# How to add accessibility feature to my element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to build accessibility feature on the bootstrap popover window for Angular.

I have something like

```
 <a href="" data-trigger="focus" tabindex="1" data-placement="top" pop-elem>
   Open a popover                                             
  </a>
```

in my directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('popElem', ['$popover',
    function($popover) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                $popover(elem, {
                    scope: scope,
                    trigger: 'focus',                
                    template: 'test.html'
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Test.html

```
<div class="popover" role="tooltip">
    <div class="popover-content">
        <div>            
            <a class="btn"
               href="">Item 1</a>
        </div>
        <div>            
            <a class="btn"
               href="">Item 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to build accessibility on the popover in my case. Everytime I press Tab key the popover will disappear. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Find in the source code what is making the popover to disapear, then catch the tab event and use `preventDefault` / `stopPropagation` so it is not intercepted by the tooltip code.

Comment: I would recommend to use a modal from angular-ui-bootstrap. There you'll have the tab feature working with-out additional coding. Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/cvfz3vwL/).